# Convert an int array into a Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, imageview

I need to convert an int array into a Bitmap. Here is what I've tried (assume that myBmp is an array of ints that represent pixel values).

```
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(outBmp, 100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setImageBitmap(myBmp);
```

What is supposed to happen is that I see the image being displayed on screen (after the array becomes that image). However, all I see is an empty screen.

Is there an alternative way to take an int[] array and convert it into a Bitmap, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you create an `InputStream` from the array and then use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yourStream)` to create the bitmap? Another suggestion is to place a breakpoint after the first line and see what value is in `myBmp`. Also, in your question are we to assume that `outBmp` is the array of ints?

Comment: One more thing, could you confirm that the value of int in the array correspond to the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) format that Android accepts? Make sure to set the transparency/alpha also. If you don't, it will be interpreted as full transparent. (Compare 0xFF0000 "transparent red" vs 0xFFFF0000 "opaque red")

Comment: @CodeMonkey, yes, outBmp is an array of ints, I forgot to mention that.